# Finding cycle index of matrix group

Tags: group-theory

I need hint to find cyclic index if this matrix group \begin{pmatrix}
  k & 0 \\
  m & 1 \\  
 \end{pmatrix}

where $k,m \in Z_5$

Comment: You're asking for the *order* of the element $g = \begin{bmatrix} k & 0 \\ m & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ in the group $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_5)$?

Comment: I need cycle index of that group

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  You're looking at the group $G$ consisting of elements of that given form for any $k, m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

There are two interesting subgroups:
$$
H = \biggl\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ m & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
{\;\Large\mid\;\;} m \in \Bbb{Z}_5 \biggr\}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
K = \biggl\{ \begin{bmatrix} k & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
{\;\Large\mid\;\;} k \in \Bbb{Z}_5^\times \biggr\}.
$$

Now, $H$ is normal in $G$, and
$$
G \cong H \rtimes K \cong C_5 \rtimes C_4.
$$